# Put random points into a specific 2D subregion

Tags: functions, random, probability-or-statistics, plotting

I want to cover a particular subregion of the x-y plane with a random distribution.

As this particular region is not a circle I encounter some problems declaring the permitted zone where to put points.

The points must NOT be drawn in the blue zone. As in the graph[image]

And I use the following code to drawing the graph:

```
mu = 0.000954;
h = x^2 - y^2 + 2 (1 - mu)/Norm[x + mu] + 2 mu/Norm[1 - x - mu];
S = 
  RegionPlot[h < 3.07, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 200, Axes -> True, Frame -> False]
```

Where `h` is the function.

**P.s.:** the drawing process is a bit long if you use more then 200 points, so keep this not so high.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
f[x_, y_] = h - 3.07;
```

Then, drawing candidates

```
dat = {RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-2, 2}], np], 
       RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-2, 2}], np]} // Transpose;
```

and selecting

```
Show[Select[dat, f @@ # > 0 &] // ListPlot[#, AspectRatio -> 1] &, S]
```

[image: dots]

the corresponding data can be exported as

```
Export["test.dat",dat]
```

$cat test.dat

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!
A very stupid question, if i want to save the coordinates of these points in a file how i can do that? THANKS !

Comment: in what format?

Comment: I solve by mayself the problem of output. Just to take the `data=Select[]` also out from the Show and than use `Export['output.dat',data]`.

Comment: `UniformDistribution` can represent 2D distribution: `dat = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], np]`. (+1 for post-`Select`.)

Comment: @Silvia thanks. I thought it would be called `Multi UniformDistribution`

Answer (score 4):

This is now easily done with the current region functionality:

```
With[{mu = 0.000954, val = 3.07},
     reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 - y^2 + 2 (1 - mu)/Norm[x + mu] + 2 mu/Norm[1 - x - mu] <
                          val, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}]];

(* discretize complement *)
cr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], reg]];

RegionPlot[reg, Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[1], Point[RandomPoint[cr, 5000]]}]
```

[image: random points outside a region]